# Qt5 app crashes when run from outside Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a strange issue that appeared only recently.

When I acces an external binary from inside my Qt app, the app crashes with the error:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
```

But when I run it from the "build and run" inside Qt Creator, everything runs fine when I acces the point in my application where I hit an exetrnal binary.

This is the function I hit when the app crashes from outside Qt creator

```
QString Api::getVideoFrame(QString filename, QString position)
{
    const QString ffmpeg = QDir::currentPath()+"/ffmpeg"; //mac version
    QProcess process;
    QStringList args;
    args    << "-ss" << position
            << "-i" << filename
            << "-f" << "image2"
            << "-vframes" << "1"
            //<< "-vcodec" << "bmp"
            << "pipe:1";
    process.start(ffmpeg, args);
    process.waitForFinished();

    return QString(process.readAllStandardOutput().toBase64());
}
```

It also crashes when accessing other external binaries, not only ffmpeg in this case.

I have the feeling it has something to do with the QDir::currentPath() because when I mess up the path, It also crashes from inside Qt Creator.

obviously I added the corresponding binaries next to the executable file in the Contents/MacOS/ folder

I don't really know how to debug this.. any clue how to solve this?

Comment: To begin with, you might want to debug it in a debugger? Like [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Just run the debugger from the command line, and see if you can pinpoint the crash location a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out why this happens and it is quite interresting to note that

```
QDir::currentPath()
```

has to be used with care on mac osX.

When an app is executed from within Qt Creator it returns :

```
/Volumes/LSPRO/Build/LSPRO.app/Contents/MacOS
```

including the path to te binary inside the .app package

But when you run it as a standalone app, it returns

```
/Volumes/LSPRO/Build
```

At least on my configuration...

Comment: Instead of using "cuurentpath", use QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath () and try.

Comment: Still weird that it crashes the application instead of giving an error. I mean, whatever wrong or mixed binaries you have in the other folder, still, the `ffmpeg` you run should crash, not your actual application, since from what i understand you just run an external executable, crash should come from linking or dynamic loading

Comment: @Rudolfs: That's the way MacOS handles crashing children: a signal is passed into the parent thus causing the parent to crash, too.

Answer (score 0):

`I don't really know how to debug this.. any clue how to solve this?`

Yes, I have some clue.

You could try using `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` for this scenario to get this working properly on MAC as also asserted by a user in the comment.

[Here](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/730bc064a070e886e10950ccfd59780e8976f5fd%3asrc/corelib/io/qfilesystemengine_unix.cpp#L674) you can find the filesystem engine source code though if you wanna further track the issue down with your suspect as a bug. In short, there is not much Mac specific code in there rather than Unix.

Also, in the future you may wanna consider QtMultimedia rather than dealing with QProcess and external execution.